# How to get words frequency in text

Tags: php

I know how to get one word frequency in a text using explode and some array functions, but what I am really looking for is to get the frequency of 2 words and more. For example this text:
"This is a sample text. It is a sample text made for educational purposes."

I need code to do this:
is a (2)
sample text (2)
a sample (2)
.... and so on

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some effort: What have you tried?

Comment: @MarvinLabs I would if I could that's why I am seeking help so if you can add something it would be good.

Comment: Please see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Anyone can try something, even if one does not manage to solve it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get 2 *consecutive* words:

```
$string = 'This is a sample text. It is a sample text made for educational purposes. This is a sample text. It is a sample text made for educational purposes.';

$sanitized = $even = preg_replace(array('#[^\pL\s]#', '#\s+#'), array(' ', ' '), $string); // sanitize: only letters, replace multiple whitespaces with 1
$odd = preg_replace('#^\s*\S+#', '', $sanitized); // Remove the first word

preg_match_all('#\S+\s\S+#', $even, $m1); // Get 2 words
preg_match_all('#\S+\s\S+#', $odd, $m2); // Get 2 words

$results = array_count_values(array_merge($m1[0], $m2[0])); // Merge results and count
print_r($results); // printing
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [This is] => 2
    [a sample] => 4
    [text It] => 2
    [is a] => 4
    [sample text] => 4
    [made for] => 2
    [educational purposes] => 2
    [It is] => 2
    [text made] => 2
    [for educational] => 2
    [purposes This] => 1
)
```

One improvement would be to convert the string to lowercase ?
I let the rest to you to figure out :-)

Comment: by the way do you have any way to extend this code so it can get 3 or more words too? Also I do not understand the concept behind making odd and even and if you explain the logic for me would be great.

Comment: @dxer Oh yes you could change it to 3 words, but you have to rewrite the regex and maybe add another (maybe few) lines.
The concept of "odd" and "even" is best illustrated with an example: Say I have `a b a b`. We have `a b` x2 and `b a` x1. Our regular expression checks for `word space word`, the problem is that when regex matches `a b` it will move further, so  `b a` won't be matched. When it moves further the second part will be matched `a b`.

Comment: So I though of removing the first word, and then match again. So we have `b a b`, the regex will match `b a` and move further ... This one is the "odd" one. Just a name I came up with lol. Hope it's clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
frequencies = empty array
words = explode sentence on white spaces
for each word in words :
  sanitized word = trim word and convert to lower case
  frequency[ sanitized word ] ++
endforeach
```

The `frequency` array now contains the number of times a word appeared in the sentence.

Comment: This is not what I mean, this only gets the frequency of one word, what I am seeking is the frequency of 2 words